# How to avoid extra quotes from sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, zend-framework

```
$select->join($dtr, "$dt.TableId=$dtr.TableId AND "."$dtr.".'StartTime NOT BETWEEN '.'"'.$Time.'"', array(),'left');
             $select->where->equalTo("$dt.". 'SeatingCapacity', $wherearray['Size']);
```

and its give me result like this

```
 SELECT "dining_table"."TableId" AS "TableId", "dining_table"."TableName" AS "TableName", "dining_table"."StoreId" AS "StoreId" FROM "dining_table" LEFT JOIN "dining_table_reservation" ON "dining_table"."TableId"="dining_table_reservation"."TableId" AND "dining_table_reservation"."StartTime" "NOT" BETWEEN "\"""2015""-""10""-""15" "17"":""40"":""20" AND "2015""-""10""-""15" "17"":""40"":""20""\"" WHERE "dining_table"."SeatingCapacity" = '4'
```

But I want the time in the format `NOT BETWEEN '2015-10-15 17:40:20' AND '2015-10-15 17:40:20'`

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I have edited My query. please have a look

```
<?php
$dtr="dining_table_reservation" ;
$dt="dining_table"; 
$time="2015-10-12 06:39:24";
$time2="2015-10-12 08:39:24";

$select->join($dtr, " ".$dt.".TableId=".$dtr.".TableId AND ".$dtr.".StartTime NOT BETWEEN '".$time."' AND '".$time2."' ", array(),'left');
             $select->where->equalTo("".$dt.".SeatingCapacity", $wherearray['Size']);
```

Comment: can you please post all assigned variables with its value Like $dt, $dtr, $time

Comment: $dtr="dining_table_reservation" ;$dt="dining_table" $time="2015-10-12 06:39:24"